# drawImage in Java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, drawimage

I can't display image in my applet. Using `drawImage()` in `paint()` method. The (Graphics2D) cast is part of a tutorial program. Image supposed to change every few seconds and correspond to title and the http link. Everything works but my images. I tried Oracle's tutorials and looked through other questions on stackoverflow. Tried passing different arguments to `drawImage()` method. Also I think I may have some unnecessary 'import's.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.URL;
// image libraries
import java.awt.Image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*; // for buffered image
import javax.imageio.*; // read buffered image
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage.*;

public class Ch_19_Ex_01 extends JApplet implements Runnable, ActionListener {
        String[] pageTitle = new String[5];
        String[] imageString = new String[5];
        URL[] pageLink = new URL[5];
        BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[5];
        Color butterscotch = new Color(255, 204, 158);
        int current = 0;
        Thread runner;

public void init() {
    pageTitle = new String[] {
        "Horoscope for cancer",
        "Brainy Quotes",
        "NJ Daily Lottery",
        "Daily Jokes",
        "West Milford weather",
    };
    imageString = new String[] {
        "0.jpg",
        "1.png",
        "2.png",
        "3.jpg",
        "4.gif",
    };
    pageLink[0] = getURL("http://my.horoscope.com/astrology/free-daily-horoscope-taurus.html");
    pageLink[1] = getURL("http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/daily_life.html");
    pageLink[2] = getURL("http://www.state.nj.us/lottery/home.shtml");
    pageLink[3] = getURL("http://www.jokes.com/");
    pageLink[4] = getURL("http://www.weather.com/weather/today/90005");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), imageString[i]);
            images[i] = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // dont know
        }
    }
    Button goButton = new Button("Go");
    goButton.addActionListener(this);
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flow);
    add(goButton);
    Button stopButton = new Button("Stop");
    add(stopButton);
}

URL getURL(String urlText) {
    URL pageURL = null;
    try {
        pageURL = new URL(getDocumentBase(), urlText);
    } catch (MalformedURLException m) {
        System.out.println("Error>>>>");
    }
    return pageURL;
}

public void paint(Graphics screen) {
    Graphics2D screen2D = (Graphics2D) screen;
    screen2D.setColor(butterscotch);
    screen2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    screen2D.setColor(Color.black);
    screen2D.drawString(pageTitle[current], 5, 60);
    screen2D.drawString("" + pageLink[current], 5, 80);
    screen2D.drawImage(images[current], 0, 0, 100, 200, this);
}

public void start() {
    if (runner == null) {
        runner = new Thread(this);
        runner.start();
    }
}

public void run () {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while(runner == thisThread) {
        current ++;
        if (current > 4) {
            current = 0;
        }
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error>>>>>>>>>>>");
        }
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (runner != null) {
        runner = null;
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (runner != null) {
        runner = null;
    }
    AppletContext browser = getAppletContext();
    if (pageLink[current] != null) {
        browser.showDocument(pageLink[current]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of `// dont know`, use `e.printStackTrace()`, which will at least tell you when something goes wrong...

Comment: Great thank you 'MadProgrammer'

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, your paint code should work fine

The problem is, most likely, in the fact that the images are not loading, but since you've chosen to ignore any errors that are raised by this process, you won't have any idea why...

So, instead of `// dont know`, use `e.printStackTrace()` when loading your images

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), imageString[i]);
        images[i] = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will at least provide you with some more clues as to the problems you are facing.

You should also avoid using AWT (`Button`) components on Swing (`JAppelt`) containers.  They tend not to play nice well together.

Having said all that, I would encourage you not to use `JAppelt` as a learning tool.  Applets come with a swag of their own issues which are difficult to diagnose at the best of times, more so when you're trying to learn Java and the Swing API.  The Swing API is complex enough with adding unnecessary challenges.

You should also avoid extending from top level containers (in this case, you have no choice), but you should also avoid painting directly to top level containers.  Apart from the complexities of the paint process, they are not double buffered, which introduces flickering when the UI is updated.

Instead, start with something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  `JComponent`s are double buffered by default, so they won't flicker when they are repainted.  You must also call `super.paintXxx`.  As I said, the paint process is a complex process, each `paintXxx` method is a link in the chain, if you break the chain, you should be prepared for some strange and unexpected behaviour down the track.

Once you have your component setup, you are free to choose how to deploy it, by adding it to something like a `JFrame` or `JApplet`, making your component more flexible and reusable.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

The next question that comes to mind is why?  Why do any custom painting at all, when `JLabel`s will not only do the job, but would probably do it better.

Take a look at [Creating an GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details...